# Why should $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$ be limited on $\mathbb{C}-\{z:\Re(z)\leq0\}$ to be considered as an analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, multivalued-functions

A multivalued function $f(z)$ can be analytic on an open set $\Omega$ where $f(z)$ has an unique value and is differentiable on every point. If $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$, I think $\Omega$ can be defined as $\mathbb{C}$, instead of $\mathbb{C}-\{z:\Re(z)\leq0\}$, which is the condition usually required for this function.

If $z=r e^{i\theta}$ with $-\pi<\theta\leq \pi$, then $\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$. Thus, $\sqrt{z}$ is clearly a single-valued function on $\mathbb{C}$.

Could you tell me why $\Omega = \mathbb{C}-\{z:\Re(z)\leq0\}$ instead of $\Omega=\mathbb{C}$? Is it because of continuity or differentiability of $f(z)$ on negative real line?

Comment: The principal square root function is not even continuous on $\Bbb C$, and yes - because of the negative real line. (If you already know the answer to your question, then why are you asking it?) It should be analytic on $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$ though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't really sure that $\sqrt{z}$ is not continuous on the negative real line, but my sixth sense told me it might be not.

Comment: Well, as you traverse over it, the phase jumps between $-\pi$ and $+\pi$. That's clearly not continuous.

Comment: Yeah, it now looks obvious to me, but I was blind for a while. I appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposed function isn't even continuous on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \operatorname{Re} < 0, \operatorname{Im} = 0\}$ let alone differentiable. For example, note that

$$\lim\limits_{\theta \to \pi^-}\sqrt{e^{i\theta}} = \lim\limits_{\theta \to \pi^-}e^{i\theta/2} = e^{i\pi/2} = i$$

but

$$\lim\limits_{\theta \to -\pi^+}\sqrt{e^{i\theta}} = \lim\limits_{\theta \to -\pi^+}e^{i\theta/2} = e^{-i\pi/2} = -i.$$

Therefore $\lim\limits_{z \to -1}\sqrt{z}$ doesn't exist, so it isn't continuous or differentiable at $z = -1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\text{Hint}:\ \cdot f(z) = \sqrt{z} = e^{\frac{1}{2} \ \log(z)}.$$

This link will answer our question.
[Log](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74485/define-a-principal-branch-in-complex-analysis)